# How to POST JSON data object to server in iOS7

Tags: json, post, ios7, sqlite

Hi in my application i have stored data in my local database sqlite3. Now i have to upload the data form local database sqlite3 to online server. For retrieving the data i have used the dataDictionary to get all the data form the sqlite3 database. And i have converted the data in json format now the problem is how to pass this json data into my online server.

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self openDB];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM reg"];
    const char *query_stmt = [sql UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK) {
     while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

        NSMutableDictionary *_dataDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSString *date = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
        field1Str= date;

        NSString *customer = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
        field2Str = customer;

        NSString *code1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
        field3Str = code1;

        NSString *code2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,3)];
        field4Str = code2;

        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field1Str] forKey:@"Kname"];
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field2Str] forKey:@"kphone"];
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field3Str] forKey:@"karea"];
        [_dataDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",field4Str] forKey:@"kcity"];

        [array addObject:_dataDictionary];


        NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        NSURL *someURLSetBefore =[NSURL URLWithString:@"my url for inserting the data into my online server"];
        [request setURL:someURLSetBefore];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

        // print json:
        NSLog(@"JSON summary: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        [connection start];
     } 
    }
```

I have used this above code to pass my sqlite3 database data to my server. I have print the jsondata in log its coming as a json format data only. Please tell me how to push this data to my online server where I'm missing in the code i have stuck here for very long time its eating my head its not working please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use some proper framework for HTTP communication. Using Apple's low-level API can be quite tricky.

This is a great framework: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: above code works fine but its storing empty value in my database please